# Injecting Environment Variables in Spring Boot Application with AWS CodeBuild

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, yaml, aws-codebuild

We are using AWS as our Spring Boot application CI/CD & hosting solution. Here are the actual services and their purpose in our integration:

1. **CodePipeline** listens for the latest changes on the git repo and starts the build process
2. **CodeBuild** builds an actual `.jar` file
3. **CodePipeline** saves previously created file to `S3` bucket and deploys it to `Elastic Beanstalk` instance

Everything works like a charm. The problem lies in injecting the Spring Boot environment variables.

We are using YAML configuration files with profiles in order to provide variables to our application. We, obviously, don't want to keep our `.yml` files in our git repo, but since they are quite big (70+ variables), the option of specifying each and every variable in `buildspec` seems too much.

My question is **what are our options**? Any ideas on injecting the YAML file during the build time, without exposing it publicly somehow? Or should we go with the each variable separately.

Thanks, Sebastian

Comment: If you have that much configuration, perhaps it's time for Spring Cloud Config.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is what are our options?

A popular way of storing config variables is in [SSM Parameter Store](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-parameter-store.html).

So instead of directly injecting all your variables to CB, you would store them in the Parameter Store, and then CB would read the parameters from the store. For that you would need to add **permissions** to CB role to access the store.

If you have such a setup, then you just past **one env variable** to CB - the name of the parameter to read. As you can have multiple ones, e.g. for prod, dev or testing.